# Which traits pass through `Deref` and which don't?

Tags: rust, traits

Let's say I have a new type

```
pub struct A(Vec<u32>);
```

and let's say I implement `Deref` on it to access the vector inside. To my surprise this enables me to index into objects of type `A` and it indexes the contained vector. But it doesn't let me compare or equality test objects of type A. So the `Index` trait seems to pass through a deref but `PartialEq` or `PartialOrd` don't ([playground link](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=e35a696e637ad9b42628fe25f0c4c1a7)).

Why?  Other than experimentation, how can I tell which traits pass through and which don't?

Comment: Just guessing, I think it's the *left side* of any operator that is rewritten, i.e. `a[i]` becomes `*a.index(i)`, so `Deref` applies to `a` but not `i`. Similarly, `a + b` becomes `a.add(b)`, so `Deref` applies to `a` but not `b`.

Comment: I suspect that the difference is that `Add::add` takes `self` by value whereas `Index::index` takes `&self` by reference.

Comment: If `a1 == a2` gets rewritten as `a1.eq(&a2)`, and then `PartialEq::eq(&a1, &a2)` shouldn't deref apply to both `a1` and `a2`?

Comment: @SebastianRedl This is not true. Both use the fully-qualified syntax which does not deref, `Trait::method(&a, &b)`.

Comment: @Jmb. No. The difference is encoded into the compiler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Traits don't really pass though `Deref`. It's just that rust inserts the deref operator `*` in a lot of places. Check out the [method call reference](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/expressions/method-call-expr.html) to see how that works with the method syntax `.` which should help you understand how seemingly built-in things are just syntax sugar.

I believe the index syntax is basically the same, so when you write

```rs
a1[1]
```

it turns into

```rs
*std::ops::Index::index(&*a1, 1)
```

Comment: While I wasn't expecting it, I can understand why `Index` works, but I still don't understand why `PartialEq` *doesn't* work.

Comment: @Jim `==` doesn't do any hidden deref. It *is* what you expect.

Comment: [The docs say](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/expressions/array-expr.html) that `a1[1]` is equivalent to `*std::ops::Index(&a1, 1)` (note the lack of a `*`) and `a1 == a2` is equivalent to `std::cmp::PartialEq(&a1, &a2)`.

It's still not clear what the difference is that makes Deref apply to one but not the other.  Is it just hardcoded in the compiler?

Comment: @Jim It also says: "Rust will also insert dereference operations on `a` repeatedly to find an implementation." This is what doesn't happen with `==`.

Comment: Indeed it does, I needed to read more carefully.  Thanks for your help!

Comment: Maybe it helps to think about that this way, but this is not what the compiler does.

Answer (score 0):

Inspecting the source code of the compiler?

Well, it may not be *easier* than experimentation, but here we come...

The only operators that autoderef are the call operator `()`, the dot operator `.`, and the index operator `[]`. All other operators do not.